# Microsoft Graph API - Get message from shared mailbox - Forbidden Error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have a daemon service which acquires access_token using username/password of a user (user1@domain.com) [ Using Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplication & then using AcquireTokenByUsernamePasswordAsync to get the access token).

Azure app has scope of "Mail.Read" and Delegated Permission has been granted (which doesn't require admin consent)

I can successfully get the subscription for mailbox of user1@domain.com thus receiving notification for mails.

I am using Graph client for Subscription.

```
var subscription = new Subscription
 {
   Resource = "users/user1@domain/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages",
   ChangeType = "created",
   NotificationUrl = "NotificationUrl",
   ClientState = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
   ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow + new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15, 0) 
  };
```

user2@domain.com has shared its mailbox to user1@domain.com. On azure app I added the scope of "Mail.Read.Shared" and also made sure to click on Grant Permission ( again not admin consent required).

However even after this I only receive notifications for user1@domain.com and not for user2@domain.com

I then stumbled on https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/concepts/outlook-share-messages-folders.md

However even if I try to get the subscription by changing Resource property in above mentioned Subscription to "users/user2@domain/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages" - I receive following error

*Code: ExtensionError Message: Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: Forbidden]*

Interestingly if I use access_token received using above specified manner to initiate a get request to below url on Postman I can read the mails of shared mailbox!
(https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user2@domain.com/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages)

Also when I tried same thing on graph explorer after modifying permissions and granting consent for Mail.Read.Shared I can read the mails.

However I get same error message when I try to acquire subscription using Postman.

Help needed on following:

1. What changes are required to get the subscription for user2?
2. Is it correct to assume that I can get access_token for user1 and then I have to setup up different subscription's for user1 & user2 in order to get notifications using a common access_token?

Comment: I suspect subscribing to a shared folder may not be supported.  Let me check with the mail team and if it isn't we should get a UserVoice item opened for this.

Comment: Thanks Darrel awaiting for confirmation!

Comment: Also in case its confirmed that subscription for shared mailbox is not yet supported, would you be able to suggest best approach for the given scenario ( there are multiple shared mail and we really want to move away from polling each one for reading new mails)